# jquery.twitter.js - update to fix twitter feed - don't understand

Tags: jquery, twitter

Trying to update the twitter feed on my website (frowey.com) as it's stopped working. Not a web developer so only figure our enough to keep the site up and running. I've downloaded Coda's recent update jquery.twitter.js v1.6 and have added the .js, min.js and the css. I'm totally stuck. The feed defaults are now in the .js, which I've updated but in the currently live and not working feed, I had the defaults on the webpage (frowey.com). The CSS is now classes and not IDs. So, I've changed what was my twitter DIV ID to twitted and have amended the CSS (applying my sizes, colours and fonts etc) but looking at the .js it's expecting classes not a DIV so the twitted DIV isn't doing anything. I don't know enough to work it through. Amended CSS is below and I know making the .twitted an ID is wrong but I'm lost. I have spent a couple of hours trying to work through the demo site for the feed but I'm still stuck!

```
div#twitterframe {
    width: 252px;
}

div#twitted {
    width: 194px;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    border: 1px solid #9c7d60;
}


.twitted h2 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.4em 1em;
    font-family:Tahoma;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #9c7d60;
}

.twitted p.preLoader {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em 1em 1em 3em;
    background: transparent url("images/loader.gif") 1em center no-repeat;
    /* generate your own loader gif: http://www.ajaxload.info */
}

.twitted ul#twitter_update_list {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 1em 0.5em 1em;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.twitted ul#twitter_update_list li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.8em 0 1em 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #9c7d60;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.twitted ul#twitter_update_list li span {
    /* tweet content */
    display: block;
}

.twitted ul#twitter_update_list li span a {
    /* links in tweet content */
    color: #6EAC00;
}

.twitted ul#twitter_update_list li a {
    /* timestamp link */
    color: #aa9689;
}

.twitted ul#twitter_update_list li.firstTweet {
}

.twitted ul#twitter_update_list li.lastTweet {
    border-bottom: none;
}

.twitted p.profileLink {
    display: block;
    padding: 0.3em 1em;
    font-family:Tahoma;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #9c7d60;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears your JSON feed URL is outdated.

Now where you need to fix this is here in `jquery.twitter.js`

Change this:

```
$.getScript("http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/"+o.userName+".json?callback=twitterCallback2&count="+o.numTweets, function() {
```

To This:

```
$.getScript("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/"+o.userName+".json?callback=twitterCallback2&count="+o.numTweets, function() {
```

Comment: Hi blamonet. Tried the change to the feed as above and left everything else as is on live site (original jquery, css etc). Still not working?